# Несколько слайдеров flickity на одной странице

Tags: javascript

Использую библиотеку [flickity](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity). Позволяет инициализировать слайдера 3 вариантами

- jquery
- vanila js
- прямо в html c помощью атрибута `data-flickity`

Использовал последний варинт и не знал бед. Однако выяснилась неприятная особенность на текущих версиях гугл хрома - иногда неправильно рассчитывается ширина фотографий в слайдере и слайды наслаивают один на другой. Если изменить размер окна - происходит пересчёт, и всё становится ок.

В библиотеке есть метод `reloadCells()`, который позволяет принудительно пересчитать размер ячеек. Но чтобы его вызвать, нужно получить инстанс слайдера. А я его не инициализирую - использую атрибут в html.

Значит, нужно делать всё в js. Библиотеку jquery не использую. Поэтому

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.main-carousel');
var flkty = new Flickity( elem, {
  // options
  cellAlign: 'left',
  contain: true
});
```

Но `querySelector` возвращает только 1 слайдер, а у меня их 2. При этом мне важно каждый слайдер запомнить в переменную и как-то потом обратиться к каждому, чтобы вызвать метод `reloadCells()`

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
flkty0.reloadCells()
flkty1.reloadCells()
});

Как решить эту задачку? Я хочу найти все `.main-carousel`, инициализировать. А потом отдельно после загрузки всей страницы вызвать для каждого `reloadCells()`?

Answer (score 0):

засунь все классы слайдеров в один массив и перебирая массив пересчитай размер ячеек

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]